# What could be the mathematical equation of the given signal?

Tags: summation, fourier-series, transformation, signal-processing, wave-equation

We know that Fourier series for periodic signal $y(t)$ is given by

$$ y(t) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty} a_m \cos(w_m t) + \sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty}b_m \sin(w_m t). \quad (2)$$

Now,I want to find Fourier series of a periodic sinusoidal signal 
$y(t)$ given below. But I don't understand how should I decide what are the harmonics present and how to calculate Fourier coefficients.

[image]

**So what could be the mathematical equation of the given signal ?**

**Note**: if there is any way than Fourier series to express the given signal in the form of mathematical equation  ,you can  explain with other way also.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the signal, it seems to have components only up to the fourth harmonic.  You can read the $y(t)$ values at intervals of $\frac T8$ from the plot-I would pick the peaks of all the obvious waves, then use the orthogonality of the [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) to compute the coefficients.  You can do that in Excel easily.

Added:  As points out, the function is odd so only sines will be involved.  It appears four terms will be enough to get close, so the form would be $$y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i \sin \frac {2 \pi i}T$$  You can just pick off the first four peaks from the graph, which seem to be at $\frac T{16}, \frac {3T}{16}, \frac {5T}{16}, \frac {7T}{16}$ and solve the four simultaneous equations for the $a_i$.  The FFT is easier if you learn how to do it, as it gives you each coefficient directly.

Comment: but how to prepare and express  given signal using mathematical equation?

Comment: You have the expression in your question, though the $\sin$ series should start with $i=1$.  What you need are the $a_i,b_i$  Because of the orthogonality, if you multiply your $y_i$ values with a $\cos$ or $\sin$ term and add them up, the sum is a multiple (depending on the number of points) of the corresponding coefficient.

Comment: how did you decide that there are "up to fourth harmonics? Also, what about phase factor of the each harmonics"? whether they are in phase or each have different phase value?

Comment: I just looked at the fact that there are four nice smooth peaks per cycle.  You clearly need fourth harmonics to show that.  They look smooth enough you probably don't need anything higher, but that is a guess.  Doing it by hand I would start with up to fourth, plot the result, and see if it is close enough.  The fact that you use both cosine and sine takes care of the phase.  The phase of the $i$th harmonic is represented by the ratio $a_i/b_i$

Comment: what could be mathematical equation of the given signal waveform?

Comment: I agree with Ross, then one could see that the function is odd so there will be only sines.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate it's Fast Fourier Transform, but choose to only calculate the frequencies you need.

To express Fourier series in terms of a continous Fourier transform, we need to introduce [Theory of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) as the fourier transform of sines and cosines are sums of [Dirac distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). If we are fine with considering the discrete fourier transform (DFT) then fourier series and the DFT coincide.

Combine this with the fact that the Fourier transform is linear and you will be done.

Comment: but  how to do it mathematically.? For finding fast Fourier transform, how to first prepare mathematical equation of given signal?

Comment: Do you have a formula for the function? Then you can calculate it with some resolution (an even power of 2) over one period.

Comment: I am just having above signal waveform which is periodic sinusoidal power signal.

Comment: So do you have any programming language to calculate it in?

Comment: no,I don't have programming language for calculation. I want to find Fourier series of the given signal mathematically.

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of the question. The FFT is a numerical technique, not something you'd implement yourself by hand.

Comment: What? Of course you can implement it yourself. I've implemented it several times. And regardless of the FFT, the other 4 lines in the answer explain theoretically for continous fourier transform. But it seems you did not read them..?

Comment: @mathreadler what could be mathematical equation  of the given signal?

Comment: It seems to me that it has at most 3 or maybe 4 over-tones, so it should be enough with 4 sines and cosines. But that is just by ocular inspection. Probably one would want to put it into a computer program for more careful analysis.